# Custom Excel-Function throws error when workbook is refreshed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a custom Excel-Function

```
Public Function getDate(interval, no)

    getDate = Format(DateAdd(interval, no, Date), "dd.mm.yyyy")

End Function
```

When I enter this function in a cell it works as expected.
However, when I open a file, which does already have the function used, it produces an `#Value!` Error.

Example input of a cell: `=">" &getDate("ww";-1)` normally the result is: 
`>30.07.2015`

I do also use the Bloomberg Excel-Addin and have Bloombergfunctions used in cells. But these work without any problems.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?
best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is either a partial answer or a full answer. Your function contains `Date` -- which suggests that you want the function to be `Volatile` but UDFs are non-volatile by default. If you put

`Application.Volatile`

as the first line in `getDate` then it will update automatically as the date changes.

Perhaps the problem is that when you open a file at a later date Excel somehow detects a dependency on the date but is unable to recalculate it. I can't reproduce your bug and I don't have this Bloomberg Addin, so I don't know if this is *the* bug, but it does seem like *a* bug.

Another thought -- to use add-ins you don't need to save as a macro-enabled workbook but to use UDFs you need to. I don't think this is the problem, but you should double-check that it is saved as a macro-enabled workbook and that is opened with security settings which enable it.

If these suggestions don't solve it -- see if you still get the error without that add-in installed.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I was able to contact bloomberg and they told me, that they have a `getDate` function in their addin, which is not shown anywhere in excel. Therefore, the multiple macro-name was the cause of error.